# C# using Privoxy/TOR

Tags: c#

I find many example how use Privoxy/TOR for proxy. For example: [How to use Tor to make a C# HttpWebRequest](http://www.krio.me/use-tor-to-make-a-c-sharp-httpwebrequest/)

First I installed Vidalia Bundle and than also Privoxy.

Vidalia Bundle using address 127.0.0.1:9115
Privoxy using address 127.0.0.1:8118

I try in code create request on server http://whatismyipaddress.com/.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://whatismyipaddress.com/");
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8118"); 

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")))
    {
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

But this server still see my IP address. What I am doing wrong ? Any advance, thank you.

Edit, with leppie advice:
I use this constructor :

```
   request.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1",8118);
```

But server still see my IP adress. :(

Application is using Privoxy on port 8118. I need foward on 9115-this is TOR port.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the url is wrong.

You should probably use the `WebProxy(string Host, int Port)` constructor.

Comment: I use this             request.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1",8118); , but the server still see my IP address :(

Comment: @Lucas: You will to debug the packets with WireShark or something. I can't help further.

Answer (score 0):

This works for a remote proxy:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://whatismyipaddress.com/");
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("110.139.166.78:8080");

using (var req = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Have you tried to do the same thing with Internet Explorer? Try to set the proxy in there: navigate the page and if the server still sees the IP there is something wrong in Privoxy.