# Forwarding HttpRequests to TOR using Privoxy

Tags: c#, tor, http-proxy

**Scope:**

I am trying to get all my HttpRequests issued via C# to get routed through the TOR Network.

After some quick research I've found some stack overflow questions like [This One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962483/c-sharp-using-tor-as-proxy) and [This One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960114/c-sharp-using-privoxy-tor), so i followed their examples and tried it myself.

**Code Sample:**

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
    "http://whatismyipaddress.com/"
);
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8118"); 
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(
        response.GetResponseStream(),     
        Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
    ))
    {
        string resp = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

**Results:**

I have Privoxy installed and running (`netstat -b -a` shows it is running/listening on the port 8118).

The Request is not logged onto the Privoxy client, although it seems like it is working.

**The Problem:**

As the user @Junior Mayhé have pointed out, i have to uncomment this line on the privoxy config file

```
forward-socks5   /               127.0.0.1:9050
```

After doing so, my web requests start to get `Error 503 - Server Unavailable`.

I have tried starting the Tor Browser but it still raises me this error.

What am i doing wrong?

**Edit One:**

After playing a bit with `Netstat -b -a` seems like Firefox's Tor is actually running on `Port:9151` instead of `Port:9050` as stated by these older questions.

After changing the port number on the Privoxy config file to 9151 i no longer get the Server Unavailable error, instead i get a Operation TimedOut. I already increased the value of the request timeout (both connection timeout and readwrite timeout) to 2 minutes and i still get this error.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: and you've edited it to have the tor tag in the title

Answer (score 0):

Maybe missing a period? That's what I have in my config file.

```
forward-socks5   /               127.0.0.1:9050 .
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this port: 9150 in privoxy settings. Worked for me